# Como faço para renderizar na tela com reactjs uma imagem que eu quero que o usuário escolha diretamente no seu computador?

Tags: react

Estou desenvolvendo um app que tem a proposta de ajudar a encontrar animais perdidos e queria o que o usuário conseguisse fazer upload de uma foto do animal e que quando ele fizesse tal ação a foto fosse renderizada na tela!

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Formulario.css'

function Formulario() {

```
const[Form,setForm] = useState({"Nome":"","Data":"","Caracteristicas":"","Foto":""})

const[list,setList] = useState([])

function handlechange(e){
    if(e.target.getAttribute("name")==="FormNome"){
        setForm({"Nome":e.target.value})
    }
    else  if(e.target.getAttribute("name")==="FormCarac"){
       setForm({"Nome":Form.Nome, "Caracteristicas":e.target.value, "Data":Form.Data,"Foto":Form.Foto})
   }
   else  if(e.target.getAttribute("name")==="FormData"){
    setForm({"Nome":Form.Nome, "Caracteristicas":Form.Caracteristicas,"Data":e.target.value,"Foto":Form.Foto})
}   
// else  if(e.target.getAttribute("name")==="FormFoto"){
//     setForm({"Nome":Form.Nome, "Caracteristicas":Form.Caracteristicas,"Data":Form.Data,"Foto":e.target.value})
// }
   }
   function handleAdd(e){ 
    setList([...list,Form])
    e.preventDefault()
}

return (
    <div>
    
        <form>
            <input type={'text'} name="FormNome"
             placeholder={"nome do seu animal"} value={setForm.Nome}
             onChange={(e)=>handlechange(e)}
             />

            <input type={'date'} 
            name="FormData"
            onChange={(e)=>handlechange(e)}
            value={setForm.Data}/>

            <input type={'file'} 
            name="FormFoto"
            // onChange={(e)=>handlechange(e)}
            value={setForm.Foto}
            />

            <input type={'text'} 
            placeholder={"Conte mais sobre seu animal, Ex: caracteristicas"}
            value={setForm.Caracteristicas} name="FormCarac"
            onChange={(e)=>handlechange(e)}
            />
            <button onClick={handleAdd}>adicionar</button>
        </form>
        
           {list.map((item,key)=>(
            <section key={key} className='Dados'>
            <h1>{item.Nome}</h1>
            <h3>Sumiu no dia: {item.Data}</h3>
            <p>{item.Caracteristicas}</p>
            <img src={item.Foto} ></img>
           </section>
            ))}
           

    </div>
);
```

}

export default Formulario;

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode tentar usar o URL.createObjectURL(), ele recebe como parâmetro o seu arquivo vindo do input file, por exemplo:

```js
else if(e.target.getAttribute("name")==="FormFoto"){
   const file = {
      fileContent: e.target.files[0]
      picture: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
   }
   setForm({"Nome":Form.Nome, "Caracteristicas":Form.Caracteristicas,"Data":Form.Data,"Foto": file.picture})
}
```